# Kafka consumer rebalancing condition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What if I create a consumer `C1` with group `consumerGroup` to read data from topic `A`. And some time later create consumer `C2`, in same group, to read data from topic `B`.

Will creation of consumer `C2` trigger rebalance?
As a more general question, when kafka will perform rebalance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time a new consumer joins the group or a consumer leaved the group (actively by calling `close()` or via timeout) a rebalance will be triggered.

Furthermore, if you subscribe to a topic that is not created yet, a rebalance will be triggered after the topic got created. Same, if a topic you subscribed to gets deleted. Also if the number of partitions for any subscribed topics get changed. Last but not least, if you subscribe via pattern, if a new topic matches the pattern or a matching topic gets deleted or if the number of partitions get changed for any matching topic, rebalance will happen.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+0.9+Consumer+Rewrite+Design